# rippled SSL-Certificate

Tags: ssl, websocket, xrp, rippled

I want to have a secure connection to my rippled node. That is why I want my node to use the `SSL-Certificate` of my domain when I connect to it via websocket or grpc. I saved the certificate and the key at `/etc/ssl/certs/server.pem` and `/etc/ssl/private/server.pem`. But if I configure `ssl_key = /etc/ssl/certs/server.pem` and `ssl_cert = /etc/ssl/private/server.pem` my node won't start.

Are these the wrong fields? What else do you need for information?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe those are the correct fields. Make sure you've put them in the `[server]` stanza of your `rippled.cfg` file. You can learn about the stanzas and fields of the config file by reading the comments in the example file: https://github.com/ripple/rippled/blob/develop/cfg/rippled-example.cfg

Can you share the relevant sections of your `rippled.cfg` file?

If you are unsure how to format or edit the file, you can also try the XRPL Node Configurator: https://xrplf.github.io/xrpl-node-configurator

When you say that your node won't start: What does it do instead? Do you get an error message?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I started the server I never got an error. So I always tried to get the status and it always just showed that the service was inactive. Yesterday for some reason it finally returned that the service had no permission to open the SSL key file. So it was actually an easy fix.

Answer (score 0):

The rippled service had no permissions to open the directory where I stored the SSL key.